# Can't serialize virtual properties in schmittjoh/serializer

Tags: php, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

One of my classes that I'm serializing has a virtual property that I would like to see. I'm using yaml configuration.

Here's the yaml:

```
Namespace\Model\Keg:
   exclusion_policy: ALL
   properties:
      A list of properties that work
   virtual_properties:
      getKegImage:
         serialized_name: image
```

Here's the class:

```
namespace Namespace\Model;

class Keg extends ModelAbstract
{
       /** Some properties + accessors **/

       /**
       * @param bool $asImgTag Whether or not to return the URL in an <img> tag
       * @return array
       */
       public function getKegImage ($asImgTag = false)
       {
               return [
                    'Key' => 'value',
                    'Key' => 'value',
                    'Key' => 'value'
               ];
       }
}
```

When I serialize the model, I would expect the to see an image field in the json with the array as its value. Instead, the field is missing. I've tried many combinations of settings in the yaml file and I can't get it to show.

Comment: Hmmm seems correct based on the [test fixture](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/tests/JMS/Serializer/Tests/Metadata/Driver/yml/ObjectWithVirtualProperties.yml) Did you by chance try running the tests to see if passes?

Comment: I'll give that a go and see what's up

Comment: The tests pertaining to that fixture seem to pass -- there were failures and error, just not in that area as far as I could tell -- however I couldn't find a way of making sure whether the metadata read by the serializer came from yml, xml, or doctrine annotations.

Comment: Just tried something: I deleted the yml fixtures and reran the tests. The output was exactly the same, which leads me to believe that those virtual property tests don't check functionality for yml

Comment: I did see a thread on github about adding virtual property support and at the time it seemed that it was added for annotations but was not working for XML, and I would then assum YML. But that was from 2013 or 2012...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the code, it looks like virtual properties aren't supported using yaml metadata. Luckily, you can mix metadata sources if you want. I simply added the @VirtualProperty Doctrine annotation to the method and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual properties are supported in YAML as of now.

For fellow Googlers, if you are using `groups`, make sure that you list them in the virtual property definition as well **even though the official YAML reference does not list them as possible values**.